# Water leaks out of spout when the shower is on

Tags: shower

The faucet leaks while the shower is on. I removed the spout and all there is, is a pipe coming out of the wall. Do I have to remove the tiles to get at whatever is behind them or can I fix this problem as it is, i.e. pipe only coming out of the wall.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If the shower diverter knob is on the faucet itself, then that can also happen if there is low water pressure to the shower. The type of spout you have uses some of the water pressure to seal the gaps that would otherwise allow water to come out of the spout. The easiest thing to try would be to simply unscrew the faucet from the pipe and replace with another of the same type and see if it works better. If not, then your issue has more to do with the shower water pressure being too low.

If that is not the case, then replacing any different kind of diverter may require working inside of the wall. Access to most shower plumbing is usually done from the opposite side of the wall, in another room.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the diverter is built into the spout?

If that's the case, the diverter simply blocks the "pipe", so water flows to the shower instead.

If it's leaking when the shower is on, then it's not entirely blocking the "pipe". You can either repair the spout you have, or replace it with a new spout.

Without knowing more about the type of spout you have, I can't provide steps to repair it.